# How to select all the nodes on prime angular p-tree?

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, tree, primeng

I have this data on p-tree (primeng), I want to know if is possible to put all the values selected in the initial load. I was trying to put a new array on 'selectedFiles', with the the current data, the parents and children in the same level, on the array, only working with the parent node, but with the child nodes is not working.

Data:

```
 this.filesTree = [
    {
        "label": "Documents",
        "data": "Documents Folder",
        "expandedIcon": "fa-folder-open",
        "collapsedIcon": "fa-folder",
        "children": [{
                "label": "Work",
                "data": "Work Folder",
                "expandedIcon": "fa-folder-open",
                "collapsedIcon": "fa-folder",
                "children": [{"label": "Expenses.doc", "icon": "fa-file-word-o", "data": "Expenses Document"}, {"label": "Resume.doc", "icon": "fa-file-word-o", "data": "Resume Document"}]
            },
            {
                "label": "Home",
                "data": "Home Folder",
                "expandedIcon": "fa-folder-open",
                "collapsedIcon": "fa-folder",
                "children": [{"label": "Invoices.txt", "icon": "fa-file-word-o", "data": "Invoices for this month"}]
            }]
    }
];
```

Angular code:

```
export class TreeDemo implements OnInit {

msgs: Message[];

@ViewChild('expandingTree')
expandingTree: Tree;
selectedFile: TreeNode;
constructor(private nodeService: NodeService) { }

ngOnInit() {

  this.nodeService.getFiles().then(files => this.filesTree = files);
}

selectAll(){
 // with the parent nodes is working 
 this.selectedFiles = this.filesTree.map(
  files => {
    ... files
 })
 //this is an example of how I want to store but is not working
 this.filesTree
  .map(files => {
    this.selectedFiles = files.children
      .map( file => {
        return {
          ... file,
          parent: files
        };
    });
  });

}
```

Template:

```
<h3>Multiple Selection with Checkbox</h3>
<p-tree 
 [value]="filesTree" 
 selectionMode="checkbox" 
 [(selection)]="selectedFiles">
</p-tree>
<div>Selected Nodes: 
 <span *ngFor="let file of selectedFiles2">{file.label} </span>
</div
```

Answer (score 2):

First, method for adding all nodes to an array

```
flattenTree(node : TreeNode)
{   
    this.arr.push(node);

    if (node.children) 
    {
        node.children.forEach(childNode => {
            this.flattenTree(childNode);
        } );
    }
}
```

Then set selectedItems = array of all nodes

```
test(node)
{
    this.filesTree11.forEach(node => {
        this.flattenTree(node);
    });

    this.selectedItems = this.arr; // select all nodes
}
```

Comment: Where to call this test(node) function ?

Comment: @Maulik It's just a JavaScript function, so anywhere you like

Comment: yeah I got it. My bad.

Answer (score 0):

You're most likely going to have to write a recursive function to step through each item's children to add the items to the `selectedFiles` variable as the data variable `filesTree`, although an array, is only an array of the top level parents.